# ScrollTo Plugin not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I recently tried to use the plugin **scrollTo** of Flesler.

Unfortunately I can not make it work.
My code looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/4kfYG/1

For example, using the following code

```
$ (window).load(function () {
   / / Scroll the whole document
   $ ('# blue'). scrollTo ('section.blue', 2500, {easing: 'elasout'});
});
```

almost nothing happens. I do not understand what is causing this problem

I hope someone with more knowledge about it can help me.
**Thanks in advance to all**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont't remember include `jQuery` and `scrollTo` plugin into page?

```
$(document).on('click', '#blue' function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 2500, {easing: 'elasout'});
});
```

Comment: I do not know why, just enter your code by clicking on the link you go faster in the section without effect

Comment: @MarcoGurnari, include http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ `Jquery Easing Plugin`, for use easing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I used a similar code:

$ ("# nav ul li a [href ^ = '#']"). on ('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault ();
    $ ('html, body'). animate ({scrollTop: $ (this.hash.) offset (). top}, 300);

But you know how I could add an additional distance? For example, top 100?

Comment: @MarcoGurnari, `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top + 100}, 300);` no? Or I dont't right understand you ...?

Comment: The effect is just what I wanted.
Thank you very much indeed;)

Answer (score 1):

- Clean whitespaces, it's important
- Properly include JQuery
- Properly include scrollTo
- Easing "elasout" is not a standard easing. For various easing options use [Jquery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/4kfYG/18/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Scroll the whole document
    $(document).scrollTo('section.blue', 2500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, your code seems to work.
If I wanted that was enabled with the click of the link, how should I do?

Thanks again for the response

Comment: Thanks again for your time
But I have a problem: the console google detects a problem in the last line:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token}

What is the reason and why it does not run the 'effect? I'm going crazy: (

Answer (score 0):

Please See The Docs and [Orginal Demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/). u need to add `jquery.localscroll-min.js` and `Html` target with `<div id="content"></div>`.

Js:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    /**
     * Most jQuery.localScroll's settings, actually belong to jQuery.ScrollTo, check it's demo for an example of each option.
     * @see http://flesler.demos.com/jquery/scrollTo/
     * You can use EVERY single setting of jQuery.ScrollTo, in the settings hash you send to jQuery.LocalScroll.
     */

    // The default axis is 'y', but in this demo, I want to scroll both
    // You can modify any default like this
    $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';

    // Scroll initially if there's a hash (#something) in the url 
    $.localScroll.hash({
        target: '#content', // Could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
        queue:true,
        duration:1500
    });

    /**
     * NOTE: I use $.localScroll instead of $('#navigation').localScroll() so I
     * also affect the >> and << links. I want every link in the page to scroll.
     */
    $.localScroll({
        target: '#content', // could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
        queue:true,
        duration:1000,
        hash:true,
        onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
            // The 'this' is the settings object, can be modified
        },
        onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
            // The 'this' contains the scrolled element (#content)
        }
    });
});
```

See Wroked Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4kfYG/15/)